# How can I compile the CIFS filesystem for a DLINK DNS-323 box?

Tags: linux, nas

How can I find/compile/install the CIFS filesystem for a DLINK DNS-323 box?

**Updated**: for added clarity: the CIFS module is nowhere to be found. Firstly, I need an indication as to how I can procure this module and secondly how to compile & install the said module on my DNS-323.

**Updated2**: I am running firmware version 1.07.

Comment: is there some reason none of the options i presented in my Oct 13th answer will work for you?

Comment: @~quack: because all the material you have provided does not lead me to resolving my situation.

Comment: ah.  it might be helpful if you indicated what firmware your DNS-323 currently uses.

Comment: added some details for you.  g'luck!

Comment: i appreciate the points, but you could've just left it open.  if the timer expires and no post has been voted up (minimum 2 pts, i believe), the bounty would expire and no answer would be auto-selected (leaving the question open for more answers).

Comment: if you decide to open another question on this topic, we'll probably need a lot more info from you regarding what you've tried and what the results were, etc.  it seems like an interesting project; i wish a DNS-323 of my own to play with.  again, good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the question is "how do I enable CIFS/mount these remote CIFS shares on my DNS-323", and the device is running a micro-linux system.

Here's a basic primer on using [CIFS in general Unix](http://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Mounting_samba_shares_from_a_unix_client) clients.  CIFS is included in the linux kernel as a driver, and can be built as a module or compiled into the kernel itself.

You can try finding or compiling a module for your existing kernel, or building your own kernel to install by reflashing the device.  The first is much safer, so I'd try that unless you're experienced at this sort of thing.

- Here's one forum post discussing [module compilation](http://forum.dsmg600.info/t230-Kernel-Modules-existing-266arm2-kernel.html) for that device; it links to a directory of [prebuild modules](http://dev.skcserver.de/dns323/).  The one you want depends on your firmware, but there is a [CIFS module for the 1.03 firmware](http://dev.skcserver.de/dns323/modules_v1.03/kernel/fs/cifs/).  You also want the [SMBFS module](http://dev.skcserver.de/dns323/modules_v1.03/kernel/fs/smbfs/) as a fallback (it's an older driver and may work if the CIFS driver fails).
- Here's how to [put together a cross-compiling environment](http://wiki.dns323.info/howto:crosscompile) for recompiling the kernel and building your own modules.  If you can't find modules built for your firmware version, this is the next-easiest route to take.
- Here's some material on replacing the stock firmware with [your own Debian-based](http://www.cyrius.com/journal/debian/orion/d-link/dns-323) system.  This is the one that can brick your device if you aren't careful, so if CIFS is all you need, try the module approach first.

---

**Update**: There's [some indication](http://forum.dsmg600.info/viewtopic.php?pid=33255#p33255) that modules compiled for firmware 1.03 will work with firmware 1.07.  I [linked to the firmware 1.03 module](http://dev.skcserver.de/dns323/modules_v1.03/kernel/fs/cifs/) earlier.

In fact, [this thread](http://forum.dsmg600.info/viewtopic.php?id=4231) includes CIFS modules compiled against the 1.06 firmware, so those modules are probably preferable.  Another thread [specifically states](http://forum.dsmg600.info/viewtopic.php?id=4760) the [`cifs.1.50.ko` module (direct link)](http://forum.dsmg600.info/attachment.php?item=467) works with the 1.07 firmware.

Here's the process:

```
# insert the module you've downloaded and copied to an accessible filesystem
insmod /path/to/cifs.1.50.ko

# make your mountpoint
mkdir /mnt/sharename

# mount -- use /bin/mount for detailed messages
/bin/mount -t cifs //server/sharename /mnt/sharename -o username=username,password=password
```

This assumes an already-working telnet or SSH interface, such as that provided by the [Fonz Fun Plug](http://wiki.dns323.info/howto:ffp) scripts.

If this works, you'll need to modify your startup scripts to insert the module at boot time.  You can then add the mount to `/etc/fstab` if you want them to always be automatically mounted.

Comment: @~quack: I've already tried all of this to no avail. I'll accept your answer for your efforts. See you around!